# Adding search and replace to the "cd" command

Tags: bash, perl, replace, tcsh, cd

I'm trying to figure out a way to search and replace in the command line.  Preferably the solution would work in tcsh.  Here's what I want to do.

```
$ echo $PWD
/projects/apples/001/0440/my/files/are/here/
$ cd 0999
/projects/apples/001/0999/my/files/are/here/
$ cd oranges
/projects/oranges/001/0999/my/files/are/here/
$ cd were
/projects/oranges/001/0999/my/files/were/here/
```

The script would search from the end of the line and find the first occurrence of a matching directory structure and then cd into that directory.

I'm fluent in python and this script woulds be easy to write in this language but python runs in a process so changing the current directory of one process has no effect on the current work directory of other existing processes.

What is the best way to write such a script?  What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this task?  My directory structures can get quite large with many thousands of folders so it needs to be quick.

Comment: Write the python program you mentioned, but have it print out the dir name instead of trying to change the cwd. Then, you can use `tcsh` equivalent of the following `sh` command: `cd "$( prog.py )"`

Comment: - and obviously you can create a shell function called `cd` to do that for you so that you can write `cd 0999` instead of `cd "$(myprog 0999)"` every time

Comment: Pick one shell. If you want a tcsh answer, don't tag bash at all -- they're *utterly and entirely* incompatible.

Comment: BTW, an implementation of something like this in bash might look like `cd() { command cd "$@"; local subdir; IFS= read -r -d '' subdir < <(find . -name here -type d -print0 -exit); [[ $subdir ]] && cd "$subdir"; }` -- though I strongly, *strongly*, **strongly** advise against it.  Doing something like this will break a *lot* of scripts and idioms, and also run extremely slowly when changing into a directory with a deep structure underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `example.py` be a script that outputs some shell commands.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# example.py
print("cd foo/bar/baz")
```

Then you can execute the output of that script, in the current shell, with backticks or the `$(...)` notation.

```
mob ~ $ $(./example.py)
mob ~/foo/bar/baz $ echo $PWD
mob ~/foo/bar/baz $ /home/mob/foo/bar/baz
```

Comment: More flexible if you use `print("foo/bar/baz")` instead of `print("cd foo/bar/baz")`. This also makes it easier to handle directories with spaces in their names.

Comment: ...otherwise, if you want to correctly handle interesting directory names (including ones with spaces, syntax, etc), you need to use `pipes.quote()` and ensure that the surrounding shell includes `eval`. And that escapes content for POSIX-y shells; if the OP's serious about wanting a csh answer, that's a completely different set of issues.